# UIPanGesture is Working but UITapGesture Is not Working on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a small view that I want to be moved around the screen and tapable. So I add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move it, and a UITapGestureRecognizer to receive tap events like so:

```
        let panner = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panDidFire(panner:)))
        playerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panner)

        let tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(tapper:)))
        playerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
```

And I create the actions in the same file

```
    func viewTapped(tapper: UITapGestureRecognizer){
         fadeInButtons()
    }
    func panDidFire(panner: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let offset = panner.translation(in: view)
        panner.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        var center = playerViewController.view.center
        center.x += offset.x
        center.y += offset.y
        playerViewController.view.center = center
    }
```

The panDidFire() function is called when the user pans, but the viewTapped() function is not called at all.

Is there a trick to this? What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of going about this?

I am using Xcode 8 with swift 3

Comment: Are the gestures conflicting with each other? Call `panner.
requireGestureRecognizerToFail(tapper)` to ensure that the tapper gets first dibs at the gesture.

Comment: Most of this looks good, but why did you name your gestures (via the "let") the same as your methods? Also, please post the method code - it may help us in debugging.

Comment: panner.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(tapper) doesn't seem to do anything. I'll try changing the method names and I'll edit the post to include the method code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set to your recognizers to work with other gesture recognizer on the view. Please use method of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
   return true
}
```